# Ida- how to find connection between 2 functions

Tags: ida

I have 2 function that I want to find a connection between them.

For ex.  maybe there is function 5level up that called to those function, or another complicate connection.

How can I find it with ida or another tool.

Looks on graphes not help me ,I have more than 1000 functions

Comment: https://binary.ninja/2017/10/01/automated-opaque-predicate-removal.html

Comment: http://www.msreverseengineering.com/blog/2014/6/23/control-flow-deobfuscation-via-abstract-interpretation

Answer (score 7):

Take the following "Hello World!" program as an example.

```
void Log(char* var) {
printf(var);
}

int main() {
Log("Hello World!\n");
}
```

After compiling with `gcc`, open that executable in IDA. First choose the function from where you want to start (e.g. `main`). Go to the `main` function, right click on the disassembly window (IDA view) and choose **Proximity browser**. Alternatively press <kbd>Num -</kbd>  to open proximity browser or <kbd>Num +</kbd> to open graph view. The window will be like this:

[image: Proximity_Browser]

Right click on the `main` rectangle, select **Collapse children** and then select **Collapse parents**. Now right click on the blank area, select **Add node by name**, choose your second function to which you want to connect `main()`. Here for example I choose `printf()`.

[image: Find_path]

Now right click in the `main` rectangle, select **Find path**, choose `printf` from the find path window. You can see the connection between `main` and `printf` and also the intermediate `Log` function.

[image: main_printf_graph]